# HolyC Program doesn't wait for input?

Tags: operating-system, temple-os

I am making a simple calculator in HolyC in TempleOS by taking 3 inputs, two for numbers and one for an operator.

[image: screenshot]

The program waits for the first number and the operator but not the second number. Is there a certain function like fflush(stdin) in Holyc?

Comment: The second GetI64 is probably eating the newline that was after the operator. Try adding a dummy GetChar or GetI64 there.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I see what you mean. Instead of putting the operator in the second place, I put it as the last and added `Print("\n");` right after it. It looks like it's working perfectly fine.

Press [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQljB.png) to see my solution.